# How can I implement a button to change language on Android Studio?

Tags: java, android

I'm developing a multi-linguistic app, because it's oriented to a very diverse public. I tried to make it through a method I found googling, but while it seems to have some sense (sorry in advance, I'm not a native speaker nor a real programmer), I didn't get it to work. The method is

```
package com.example.donafelicidad;

import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.content.res.Configuration;

import java.util.Locale;


public class LanguageHelper {

    public static void changeLocale(Resources res, String locale) {

        Configuration config;
        config = new Configuration(res.getConfiguration());

        switch (locale){
            case "es":
                config.locale = new Locale("es");
                break;
            case "qu":
                config.locale = new Locale("qu");
                break;
           }
        res.updateConfiguration(config, res.getDisplayMetrics());
    }
}
```

I'm applying this method with the buttons, referenced as CHNG_QU, and CHNG_ES:

```
CHNG_QU.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                LanguageHelper.changeLocale(getApplicationContext().getResources(), "qu");
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        CHNG_ES.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                LanguageHelper.changeLocale(getApplicationContext().getResources(), "es");
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

I changed manually the locale settings, and tried it. It changed perfectly to the other language, so I guess that the Strings are well done. Any feedback about how to handle this would be greatly appreciated, even if it's necessary to re-do the entire code. Please use simple terms for a unexperienced guy who is just doing his best.

As a side note, I didn't use other threads of questions because most of what I found was deprecated.

Comment: i'm not able to help, but welcome to stack overflow :) i hope you find an answer, i'm sure there are other similar questions and topics regarding this issue, but for your first question this was asked quite well, at least in my opinion. just to confirm, you're saying that the current code isn't working, right ? it only works when you change the locale manually ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Lingver](https://github.com/YarikSOffice/lingver) is a library made to force your app to use the locale resource files you want.

In the documentation, I found [this blogpost](https://proandroiddev.com/change-language-programmatically-at-runtime-on-android-5e6bc15c758) that implements it while explaining every step, I hope you find it useful.

Comment: Hi, thanks a bunch! I'm not quite sure how to implement Lingver. I've already imported the library adding what was on the git onto build.gradle, but I'm having issues figuring out how to correctly use it. If you could explain this a bit, I'd be very grateful. Adding to that, I saw that the library was coded in Kotlin, while my app is being designed on Java. Would that be an issue? In any case, that blogspot was really explanatory.

Comment: Hey, sorry about the long wait, I wasn't able to check my SO until now.

Using Lingver inside of a Java project is not an issue, as you mentioned, since Kotlin is designed to interoperate fully with Java. If you're feeling up to the task, mixing Java and Kotlin shouldn't be an issue :(shorturl.at/HQV18).

If you'd like to continue using Java, I a quick google search found (shorturl.at/tBLU2) and (shorturl.at/dCKZ8).

Feel free to +1 & accept the answer if I helped you go down the right path, and good luck with your project :).

Edit: For some reason I can't get link formatting to work.

Comment: Thanks! I managed to make it work with some experimentation and trying. Great answer.